# PostgreSQL install of legacy.sql, osm data and PosGIS 2.0

Tags: sql, postgis, postgresql-9.2, psql

I need to use osm2pgsql on a Windows 8 (I know, :-() x64, PostGIS 2.0 and PostgreSQL 9.2. To do so I know I have to install, using the PostgreSQL console in pgAdmin III, legacy.sql amongst other things.

How can I tell if the following has run on my database?

```
psql -d osm -p 5433 -f legacy.sql
```

Currently, when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it just goes to the next line in the PostgreSQL console and doesn't really give me any confidence it has run...and the osm2pgsql functionality doesn't run, so it clearly isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, but by using cd to dir, not the PostgreSQL console, then the `psql` command. Here are all of the steps:

1. Add a user with the same name as your Windows login to the database. So that's via pgAdmin--> Login Roles. Give that user all the necessary permissions.
2. Edit the pg_hba.conf file so "Method" is trust.
3. Put `psql` on the system path (using environment variables)
4. cd to the PostGIS directory. Something like `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\share\contrib\postgis-2.0`
5. Run 'psql -d yourdbnamehere -p yourportnumberhere -f legacy.sql'

Then it ran and printed out it was creating functions.

Comment: You don't need a Postgres user with the same name as your Windows user. Just use the the `-U <username>` option or use `psql dbname username` to login with a username other than the current windows user.